# SQL MERGE only when changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-merge

On a SQL `MERGE` how do I insert a "do nothing" type statement?  For example, I have this right now:

```sql
MERGE INTO dbo.Worker AS T
USING dbo.Collector_Worker AS S
ON T.WWID = S.WWID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    T.IDSID = S.IDSID,
    ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (WWID, IDSID, ...)
    VALUES (S.WWID, S.IDSID, ...)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
     UPDATE SET T.Person_Status_Type = 'INACTIVE', T.Active = 0;
```

There are a ton of other columns where the `...` characters are.  So this works great except for the fact that it updates every row that already exists, even if there are no changes.  As the table has a million rows in it, that's a ton of unnecessary modifications.  I only want to update the row if a change was made.

If I try and just add an `AND T.IDSID <> S.IDSID` to the `ON` statement then it'll fail because it now tries to run the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I made this difficult.  All I have to do is put the extra queries on the `WHEN MATCHED` and then it all works as desired, with no updates happening unless something changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an expression expression in the `WHEN`:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.IDSID <> S.IDSID THEN
     UPDATE SET T.Person_Status_Type = 'INACTIVE',
                T.Active = 0;
```

Comment: SQL server gives an error if you try that saying `The identifier 'S.IDSID' cannot be bound. Only target columns and columns in the clause scope are allowed in the 'WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE' clause of a MERGE statement.`